# Subdomains no longer work

Tags: domain-name-system

I recently moved all my domains from one host to another. Even though I didn't change anything at all on my actual web server, none of my subdomains work anymore. What I'm working with is sniphq.com and app.sniphq.com.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have actually found the answer but I'm not sure.

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Wildcard_DNS

Apparently DreamHost doesn't support wildcard DNSs unless you also get a VPS with them? That seems lame to me if that's the case, but okay. For now I just added an A record for app.sniphq.com to point to my server's IP.

Comment: That's incredibly lame, as wildcards are a basic feature of DNS.

Comment: The page pointed to makes it clear that this isn't an arbitrary decision to not support "a basic feature of DNS", but a reasoned limitation of the automated configuration interface, forcing the use of manual reconfiguration, to stop customers from doing expensive or unsupported things that they otherwise might think themselves free to do at whim without clearing them with the service provider first.